# Black screen after BIOS splash screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, black-screen-of-death

Between 2016/09/09 ~15:00 and 2016/09/12 ~11:45, a Toshiba Satellite C670D-11K started experiencing a problem whereby the boot process shows the BIOS splashscreen but **nothing** else - no "Starting Windows", no cursor, nothing.

Notable facts:

1. Connecting to a monitor has exactly the same problem.
2. Booting to the BIOS works fine and the internal HDD (TOSHIBA MK6475GSX) is detected.
3. There are no other boot devices (USB, disc, etc) connected.
4. HDD Regenerator reported no problems for the first scan and found and repaired 1 delay on the second scan.
5. Booting to a Windows 7 install disc works.
6. Commands `diskpart`, `cd`, `dir`, etc can read the contents of the Windows disk / partition / volume fine. Although, now that I think about it, it's odd that the volume isn't labelled "Windows".
7. Start-up repair reports "Startup Repair could not detect a problem"
8. System Restore reports that 9 critical Windows updates were installed on 2016/09/10 between 00:11:38 and 00:59:51. However, System Restore-ing to a restore point taken on 2016/09/09 at 13:56:38 does not affect the problem.
9. Command `sfc /scannow` reports "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again."
10. Command `dism /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` reports:
    "The scratch directory size might be insufficient to perform this operation. This can cause unexpected behaviour.
    Use the /ScratchDir option to point to a folder with sufficient scratch space.     The recommended size is at least 1024 MB.

    Reverting pending actions from the image...
    The operation completed. Any revert of pending actions will be attempted after reboot.
    The operation completed successfully."
11. Booting normally and pressing the spacebar invokes Windows Boot Manager but pressing F8 goes to a black screen instead of invoking Advanced Boot Options like it should.
12. No DHCP leases have been issued to the device which suggests that it's not booting very far.

---

**Update: 2016/09/26 15:37**

Further notable points:

13. Command `bootrec /rebuildbcd` reports the following, regardless of current directory (`X:\sources`, `D:\`, `C:\`, `C:\boot`, etc):
    "Successfully scanned Windows installations.
    Total identified Windows installations: 0
    The operation completed successfully."
14. Command `bootrec /fixmbr` reports "The operation completed successfully."
15. Command `bootrec /fixboot` reports "The operation completed successfully."
16. CHKDSK reports no problems with the file systems on internal storage drives / partitions / volumes `C:` and `D:`

The problem still exists.

---

**Update: 2016/09/27 11:14**

Further notable points:

17. Repairing the boot sector with commands `bcdedit /export c:\bcdbackup`, `attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s`, `ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old`, `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, `y` did not resolve the problem.

---

**Update: 2016/09/27 15:32**

Further notable points:

18. Booting to a Windows 7 install disc and selecting "Repair your computer" prompted with the following:
    "Windows found problems with your computer's startup options.

    Do you want to apply repairs and restart your computer?

    Repair details:

    The following startup options with be added:
    Name: Windows Recovery Environment (recovered)
    Path: Recovery\5b9401f1-6322-11e6-9bec-acf9e6b815fb\Winre.wim
    Windows Device: Partition=D: (610378 MB)

    A copy of the current boot configuration data will be saved as C:\Boot\BCD.Backup.0001"

    Selecting "Repair and restart" did not resolve the problem.
19. Forcing SFC with command `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows` reported:
    "Beginning system scan. This process will take some time.

    Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"

    Rebooting did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Okay so if this has only happened between the 9th and the 12th, is this not an issue any longer?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The problem started some time between those dates and times. The problem still exists.

Comment: I'm thinking master boot record corruption here, sometimes that produces an error and sometimes it doesn't... I'll post a suggestion below

Comment: Have you run a `chkdsk` against the drive/filesystem yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Please see update 2016/09/26 15:37. Thanks.

Comment: It's UEFI not BIOS

Comment: @barlop No, it's an old laptop so, in this case, it's BIOS.

Comment: @mythofechelon I thought computers for a number of years now have all been UEFI.. How do you know it's BIOS and not UEFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a resolution so I reinstalled Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from the Windows 7 installation DVD
2. At the “Press any key to boot from CD or DVD…”, press any key to
   boot from the DVD
3. Select a language
4. Select a keyboard layout
5. Click Next
6. Select the operating system and click Next. The “Use recovery tools
   that can help fix problems starting Windows” must be checked when
   you select the operating system.
7. At the System Recovery Options screen, click on Command Prompt
8. When Command Prompt successfully loads, type this command:

   `bootrec /rebuildbcd`
9. Press Enter
10. Type the next command:

    `bootrec /fixmbr`
11. Press Enter
12. Type the next command:

    `bootrec /fixboot`
13. Press Enter
14. Remove the installation DVD from the disk tray and restart your computer

These steps might allow Windows to boot successfully, leave a comment if there are any errors along the way

---

Edit:

Since the BCD store exists and lists a Windows installation, you'll first have to "remove" it manually and then try to rebuild it again.

At the prompt, execute the bcdedit command as shown and then press Enter:

```
bcdedit /export c:\bcdbackup
```

The bcdedit command is used here to export the BCD store as a file: bcdbackup. There's no need to specify a file extension.
The command should return the following on screen:

```
The operation completed successfully.
```

Meaning the BCD export worked as expected.

At this point, you need to adjust several file attributes for the BCD store so you can manipulate it.

At the prompt, execute the attrib command exactly like this:

```
attrib c:\boot\bcd -h -r -s
```

What you just did with the attrib command was remove the hidden, read-only, and system attributes from the file bcd. Those attributes restricted the actions you could take on the file. Now that they're gone, you can manipulate the file more freely - specifically, rename it.

To rename the BCD store, execute the ren command as shown:

```
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
```

Now that the BCD store is renamed, you should now be able to successfully rebuild it, as you tried to do in Step 2.
Note: You could delete the BCD file entirely since you're about to create a new one. However, renaming the existing BCD accomplishes the same thing since it's now unavailable to Windows, plus provides you yet another layer of backup, in addition to the export you did in Step 5, if you decide to undo your actions.

Try rebuilding the BCD again by executing the following, followed by Enter:

```
    bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

which should produce this in the Command Prompt window:

```
    Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

    Please wait, since this may take a while...


    Successfully scanned Windows installations.
    Total identified Windows installations: 1
    [1]  D:\Windows
    Add installation to boot list? Yes<Y>/No<N>/All<A>:
```

meaning that the BCD store rebuild is progressing as expected.

At the Add installation to boot list? question, type Enter Y or Yes, followed by the Enter key.
You should see this on screen:

```
The operation completed successfully.
meaning that the BCD rebuild is complete.
```

**Restart your computer.**
Assuming that an issue with the BCD store was the only problem, Windows should start as expected.
If not, continue to troubleshoot whatever specific issue you're seeing that's preventing Windows from booting normally.
Important: Depending on how you started System Recovery Options, you may need to remove a disc or flash drive before restarting.

---

**SFC - The forced way**

System File Checker can be forced to use a specific "clean" file set (ie. the one on your Windows 7 Disk here) to check and repair a damaged file set (your HDD here). The minimal instructions are below, as you already know how to get to command prompt:

Open Diskpart
Type "list volume" and press enter
Note the drive letter of your "System Reserved" partition, and the letter of your Windows partition, then try the following command:

sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=f:\windows

Where "c:\" is the drive letter of the System Reserved partition and "f:/" is the Windows partition.

If it gives you an error we will still need to find a way to cancel the pending sfc run, which might be:

del x:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml

Where x is replaced with both drive letters above in two separate commands, then try the new sfc command again. If this doesn't work I'll update later when I can.

Comment: Please see update 2016/09/26 15:37. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, added some more details at 16:15

Comment: Everything went exactly as you said it would but, unfortunately, the problem remains. I will update my post with what we have tried.

Comment: Rats, its hard to know what to suggest when theres no error to go on. It might be time to look at using a Linux live USB drive to rescue your files, then format the windows drive and reinstall. Have you got any experience setting up a Linux USB drive to boot off?

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to that as this problem started occurring a few days after completing a lengthy reinstall (due to seemingly unrelated problems) so I wouldn't want to do it again. If no other solutions present then I'll have to go down that route (again).

Comment: Naturally we all hope as such, do you trust that this and the previous issue aren't hardware related, perhaps a hard drive issue? I do wonder if this issue stems from sfc's pending repair trying to run but failing at every startup, perhaps finding a way to cancel that is the next thing to try - I'll investigate

Comment: The previous problems seemed to be software-related (Java frames not loading properly within Sage 50 Accounts' Sage Drive authentication prompts, etc). I believe that's what the DISM commands were supposed to do but hopefully you'll find something different.

Comment: Please see update 2016/09/27 15:32. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any further advice? Thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the contents of you CBS log somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?